# Rails assets don't get updated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

I have a Rails 3.1 app and for some reason when I change CSS, the changes don't show up. I did `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` and it helped once, but now I am stuck with the old CSS no matter what.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As your assets are now precompiled you need to clean them with the following

```
bundle exec RAILS_ENV=development rake rails_group=assets assets:clean
```

Comment: hmm did not help..? /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/ruby /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/rake assets:clean:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets   btw the problem i mentioned shows up in development..

Comment: Any chance you can tell how to turn off asset precompile for development so that it is possible to see changes made in .css immediately?

Comment: Delete all the files in public/assets and stop running the precompile task! If the CSS does not show then I bet this is an upgraded app?? In that case check that all you config options match those in the Rails Pipeline Guide upgrading section.

Comment: this didnt work as a bundle exec command, `rake assets:clean:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets` worked for me though

Comment: I had the same problem and needed to remove `config.assets.digest = true` from my dev config file to get the asset cache to invalidate when assets were changed.

Comment: If you're on Chrome, try using a different tab. Myself and others found that sometimes Chrome was using caching on it's own.

Answer (score 6):

For my production environment I had to combine a few of the above steps to get my assets recompiled.

First I had to do:

```
rake assets:clean
```

Making sure I was in the right environment

Then I needed to delete the `public/assets` directory that the precompile creates (or just the file that you need to fix, `application-<hash>.css` for example)

Then finally re-run

```
rake assets:precompile
```

And restart my apache server (I use passenger with apache, not tested with nginx)

Answer (score 5):

You might want to try rake assets:clean and then rake assets:precompile

Comment: did it.. nothing changed (old css is being served).

Comment: When I did this, I noted in the error that it was performing the rake task in `rake assets:clean:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets`..once I switched it to `development` it worked nicely! :) thx.

Answer (score 3):

For me is was just deleting compiled css/js files from public directory.

It turned out that other dev put it there and didn't let know anyone.

Comment: I had to do this too, but it's not another dev, it's the precompiler.

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me in rails, chrome, mac :

1 - In terminal :

```
rake assets:clean
```

2 - In Sublime text or in Finder :

Delete the "Public > Assets" folder

3 - In terminal launch localhost server :

```
rails s
```

4 - In chrome :

```
http://localhost:3000/
```

5 - Reload chrome clearing cache if relevant :

```
cmd + shift + R
```

You should now be able to update your css files and see immediate changes on your localhost just reloading the page

**DO NOT RUN "rake assets:precompile"** in terminal because it will recreate the folder "assets" in the "public" folder and you won't be able to see updates of your css files directly in your localhost

Comment: That last note was my solution. I run `rake assets:precompile` on development just to test if everything was going to work properly on production. Then I spent 3 hours looking for this solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In case any future Googlers find this thread: I had the same problem in the test environment of a Rails 4.2.8 application. None of the above solutions worked. Setting `config.serve_static_files = false` in `config/environments/test.rb` solved it.

Bear in mind that this is a temporary fix as it causes all files in the `public` folder to no longer be served (including 404.html, favicon.ico, robots.txt, etc).