# SASS: After every change have to reboot my server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

Using: rails4 app 
Command: For Connecting and Rebooting in order to see the change.

```
rake assets:precompile
```

and

```
control + c 
rails s
```

Is it normal!! Because, sometime I have to do a lot of change and I don't want to reboot the rails server 2000 times per hour.

It's development machine.

Suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps this answer will help you:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9641320/rails-assets-dont-get-updated

Comment: this is not normal. If working with ruby webrick server, you should be able to write your sass file, without having to run `rake assets:precompile`, to see any changes.
`rake assets:clean RAILS_ENV=development` will maybe do the trick, as lsowen suggests. Check your logs for any runtime errors.

Comment: This happen on all my projects, so I think I have a problem on my rails instalation

Comment: It happened to me, using LESS though. Fixed it by removing spring gem.

Comment: assets precompiling should not be needed in your developement environment. Perhaps you did modification on your environment configuration files (`config/environments`) or it did happen automatically whenever you create a new rails app through CLI. Can you attach the log after you run `rails s` to see the environment you're running on (usually aline with the port number you're using) and also the `config/environments/development.rb` (if you're really running on development env) to see how the configurations look like? check if `config.assets.compile = true` is there, then remove it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I solve it with this command

rake assets:clobber

Thanks anyway.

Comment: deleting the entire folder of precompiled assets every time isn't really a viable solution for the development environment... You should actually enable on-the-fly asset compilation as @huwman suggests.. simply to avoid having to precompile it manually every time you change your assets.

Comment: @mrstif I don't delete the enteire folder every time, I just did this one time and everything works normal

Comment: ah! ok... so the issue here is in fact what laffuste had already commented in huwman's answer... you precompiled the assets when you weren't supposed to and wanted to clean them... you should probably change your question to reflect that... for further reference

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you're precompiling while still making changes to your SASS.

During development, if making frequent changes to SASS, I'll have cleaned my assets out and the server will pick up and compile these changes as I make them.

```
rake assets:precompile
```

is only used when I push to production

There is some guidance here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#local-precompilation on why you might want to precompile locally, but I can't speak for your own projects.

I had a lot of headaches when trying to edit js files and refresh them while my assets were precompiled and they all went away went I ditched it in dev.

Comment: I have to rake assets:precompile on my local because I can see my changes, that's the reason.

Comment: The reason you had to precompile to see your changes was because you precompile'd first when you shouldn't had to.